# Paragraph not changing to desired format in ppt with openxml

Tags: c#, xml, error-handling, powerpoint, openxml

I'm trying to edit a paragraph in pptx through changing its text, font size, font style and alignment.

This is what i have done so far:

```
  **this is the method im using to call the update paragraph**

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       
        using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open("ppturl", true))
        {
            // Get the presentation part of the presentation document.
            PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;

            // Verify that the presentation part and presentation exist.
            if (presentationPart != null && presentationPart.Presentation != null)
            {
                // Get the Presentation object from the presentation part.
                Presentation presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;

                // Verify that the slide ID list exists.
                if (presentation.SlideIdList != null)
                {
     
                        SlideId sourceSlide = presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements[0] as SlideId;
                        SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.GetPartById(sourceSlide.RelationshipId) as SlidePart;

                    updateParagraph(slidePart);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
   
**Here im extracting the title in the slide because this is what i need.**

    public static void updateParagraph(SlidePart slidePart)
    {
        if (slidePart == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("presentationDocument");
        }

        if (slidePart.Slide != null)
        {
            // Find all the title shapes.
            var shapes = from shape in slidePart.Slide.Descendants<Shape>()
                         where IsTitleShape(shape)
                         select shape;
            foreach (P.Shape shape in shapes)
            {
                D.Paragraph paragraph = shape.TextBody.Elements<D.Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();
                shape.TextBody.RemoveAllChildren<D.Paragraph>();
                AddNewParagraph(shape, "This is a new Slide");

            }
           
        }
    }


  **This is where i am trying to add a new paragraph with specific style**

    public static void AddNewParagraph(this P.Shape shape, string NewText)
    {

        D.Paragraph p = new D.Paragraph();

        P.TextBody docBody = shape.TextBody;
        Justification justification1 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center };
        p.ParagraphProperties=new D.ParagraphProperties(justification1);
        D.Run run = new D.Run(new D.Text(NewText));
        D.RunProperties runProp = new D.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 9, Dirty = false };
        run.AppendChild(runProp);
        D.Text newText = new D.Text(NewText);
        run.AppendChild(newText);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(runProp.FontSize.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
        p.Append(run);
        docBody.Append(p);

    }
```

This is giving me an error whenever im trying to open the pptx "repair pptx error".
Can someone please provide a clear solution specific to pptx and not doc.?

Thankful..

Comment: Can you open the file manually with Power Point on the machine you are using?  The error sound like a compatibility with the version of Power Point (Office) on your computer and the version of OpenXml that you are using.

Comment: Nope i couldn't, actually this error is appearing when i open it manually nothing on my IDE. @jdweng

Comment: Microsoft Office doesn't fully work with OpenXml.  Do you have a non microsoft viewer that you can use?

Comment: <a:p><a:pPr algn="ctr"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"><a:latin typeface="Arial" pitchFamily="2" charset="-78"/><a:cs typeface="Arial" pitchFamily="2" charset="-78"/></a:rPr><a:t>This is a new day</a:t></a:r></a:p> can you tell me plz how do i analyze the closing tags? how can Run start somewhere and end somewhere else ? @jdweng

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/). The following code example shows you how to change some paragraph properties with this library:

```cs
using (var presentation = new Presentation("example.pptx"))
{
    var firstShape = (IAutoShape) presentation.Slides[0].Shapes[0];
    var firstParagraph = firstShape.TextFrame.Paragraphs[0];
    var firstPortion = firstParagraph.Portions[0];

    firstPortion.Text = "New text.";
    firstPortion.PortionFormat.FontHeight = 24;
    firstPortion.PortionFormat.FontBold = NullableBool.True;

    firstParagraph.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = TextAlignment.Center;

    presentation.Save("example.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
}
```

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for .NET](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/net/). This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example shows you how to change the paragraph settings using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```cs
var slidesApi = new SlidesApi("my_client_id", "my_client_key");

var fileName = "example.pptx";
var slideIndex = 1;
var shapeIndex = 1;
var paragraphIndex = 1;
var portionIndex = 1;

var firstPortion = slidesApi.GetPortion(
    fileName, slideIndex, shapeIndex, paragraphIndex, portionIndex);

firstPortion.Text = "New text.";
firstPortion.FontHeight = 24;
firstPortion.FontBold = Portion.FontBoldEnum.True;

slidesApi.UpdatePortion(
    fileName, slideIndex, shapeIndex, paragraphIndex, portionIndex, firstPortion);

var firstParagraph = slidesApi.GetParagraph(
    fileName, slideIndex, shapeIndex, paragraphIndex);

firstParagraph.Alignment = Paragraph.AlignmentEnum.Center;

slidesApi.UpdateParagraph(
    fileName, slideIndex, shapeIndex, paragraphIndex, firstParagraph);
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.